# How to print multiple page at once from html string in flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, pdf

I have a html string and I want to print it multiple time at once without saving or reading file

I'm using Printing package but it can only print (layout) one page at once.

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
    onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => await Printing.convertHtml(
          format: format,
          html: '<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>',
        ));
```